# JStack for Java 1.5?

Tags: java, jstack

I want to use the JStack in a Java 1.5 VM.  I found in several web pages that a version of JStack exists for this version, but I can't find it.

I have versions 1.5.0_22 and 1.5.0_10 of the JDK and jstack is not included.  It is included in Java SDK 1.6

Is it a separate download? or is it included in a different revision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstack.html

**jstack is not currently available on Windows platforms or on the Linux Itanium platform.**

Do you happen to use Windows or Itanium?

Comment: At least with 1.6 it is now available in the JDK for windows.  Maybe it would attach to a 1.5 java process as well?